# Вёрстка. Не получается прижать блок слева от контейнера (мало кода)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, position, float

Есть html код:

```
<header>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="container">
     ...
    </div>
<header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дайте подсказочку, как правильно сверстать такое расположение блоков. Чтобы при отдалении, .block всегда прижимался к контейнеру. У меня получаются только кривые решения через float и position: absolute, а вот нормального придумать не могу ...

Comment: Поясните, что такое `при отдалении всегда прижимался`. И добавьте свои решения в вопрос. Так станет понятнее, чем можно помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте **css** свойство `margin-left`:

```css
.block {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-color: red;
 float:left; /* поднять над потоком и прижать влево */
}
.container {
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:yellow;
 margin-left:100px; /* значение равно ширине .block */
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Еще один способ. Разместить Container по центру и прилепить к нему блок справа.

```css
.container {
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:yellow;
 margin: auto;
 position:relative;
}
.block {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-color: red;
 position:absolute;
 left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="block">меню</div>
текст
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот только ещё такое условие, которое я не указал. У контейнера уже стоит margin:0 auto; И он находится ровно по центру страницы

Comment: тогда нужно оба блока обернуть в другой блок и перенести свойство  `margin:0 auto;` в него, так вы отпозиционируете оба блока по центру.

Comment: @BimBam добавил еще возможный вариант с `Container` по центру, смотрите обновленный ответ

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
  display: table;
}

section > * {
  padding: .25em .5em;
}

.block {
  height: 4em;
  background: silver;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="container">container</div>
<section>
```